# Ionic slides (ion-slides) : hide pagger when reaching the end

Tags: html, ionic-framework, slider, pager

I am using [ionic slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#slides) and I want to hide the pager when the user reaches the last slide.
There is a [showPagger() method](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/) but I cannot figure out how to use it for this purpose.

Any help on this?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

html :

```
<ion-slides pager (change)="onSlideChanged()">
  ...
<ion-slides>
```

js :

```
 $scope.onSlideChanged = function() {  
    if ($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex() == $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount()) {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.showPager(false);
    }
    else {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.showPager(true);
    }
}
```

I will update answer later.

Comment: I don't use ion-slide-box. It is deprecated. I use ion-slides

Comment: Somebody needs to add this to Ionic 2 Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after searching and searching I found out that it is an [open issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4987) about it in ionic repository. The showPager property is not exposed to the directive API, so there is no direct use to it.